# Can I speedup my R code with Rcpp?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, matrix, rcpp

I defined an R function that contains a matrix, a vector and a parameter `a`. I need to compute the results of the function for different values of `a`. This is simple to code in `R`, but very slow when the matrix is "big" and number of the parameter values are large.

Can I define the function in `R` and do the for loop in `Rcpp`?

Can it speed up the computations?

A minimal example of a `foo` function in `R` is

```
f <- function(X,y,a){
  p = ncol(X)
  res = (crossprod(X) + a*diag(1,p))%*%crossprod(X,y)
  }

set.seed(0)
X <- matrix(rnorm(50*5),50,5)
y <- rnorm(50)
a <- seq(0,1,0.1)

result <- matrix(NA,ncol(X),length(a))

for(i in 1:length(a)){                  # Can I do this part in Rcpp?
  result[,i] <- f(X,y,a[i])
  }

result
```

Comment: So you're only interested in answers involving `Rcpp`, not any other way of speeding it up, right?

Comment: Would this post for [fast large matrix multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923787/fast-large-matrix-multiplication-in-r) be of any help ? The `%*%` can be done using `crossprod` according to this post. It also talks about Rcpp.

Comment: If you need matrix multiplications, you can use {RcppArmadillo}. Yet, you won't gain much from the looping part because matrix computations are the same and are likely to take most of the time in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer by 李哲源 correctly identifies what should be done in your case. As for your original question the answer is two-fold: Yes, you can move the loop to C++ with Rcpp. No, you won't gain performance:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix fillMatrix(Rcpp::NumericMatrix X,
                   Rcpp::NumericVector y,
                   Rcpp::NumericVector a,
                   Rcpp::Function f) {
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix result = Rcpp::no_init(X.cols(), a.length());
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
    result(Rcpp::_, i) = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(f(X, y, a[i]));
  }
  return result;
}

/*** R
f <- function(X,y,a){
  p = ncol(X)
  res = (crossprod(X) + a*diag(1,p))%*%crossprod(X,y)
  }

X <- matrix(rnorm(500*50),500,50)
y <- rnorm(500)
a <- seq(0,1,0.01)

system.time(fillMatrix(X, y, a, f))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.052   0.077   0.075 
system.time({result <- matrix(NA,ncol(X),length(a))

for(i in 1:length(a)){
  result[,i] <- f(X,y,a[i])
  }
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.060   0.037   0.049 
*/
```

So the Rcpp solution is actually slower than the R solution in this case. Why? Because the real work is done within the function `f`. This is the same for both solutions, but the Rcpp solution has the additional overhead of calling back to R from C++. Note that [for loops in R are not necessarily slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50991437/8416610). BTW, here some benchmark data:

```
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 fillMatrixR() 41.22305 41.86880 46.16806 45.20537 49.11250 65.03886   100
 fillMatrixC() 44.57131 44.90617 49.76092 50.99102 52.89444 66.82156   100
```

Comment: After I read the excellent solution by @李哲源, I reasoned that nothing could be added here to make this post better... until I read this answer.  I really do appreciate your contributions.

Answer (score 7):

I simply suggest **avoiding recomputing `X'X` and `X'y` in the loop** as they are loop-invariant.

```
f <- function (XtX, Xty, a) (XtX + diag(a, ncol(XtX))) %*% Xty

set.seed(0)
X <- matrix(rnorm(50*5),50,5)
y <- rnorm(50)
a <- seq(0,1,0.1)

result1 <- matrix(NA, ncol(X), length(a))

XtX <- crossprod(X)
Xty <- crossprod(X, y)

for(i in 1:length(a)) {
  result1[,i] <- f(XtX, Xty, a[i])
  }

## compare with your `result`
all.equal(result, result1)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

**hours later...**

When I return I see something more to simplify.

```
(XtX + diag(a, ncol(XtX))) %*% Xty = XtX %*% Xty + diag(a, ncol(XtX)) %*% Xty
                                   = XtX %*% Xty + a * Xty
```

So actually, `XtX %*% Xty` is loop-invariant, too.

```
f <- function (XtX.Xty, Xty, a) XtX.Xty + a * Xty

set.seed(0)
X <- matrix(rnorm(50*5),50,5)
y <- rnorm(50)
a <- seq(0,1,0.1)

result2 <- matrix(NA, ncol(X), length(a))

XtX <- crossprod(X)
Xty <- c(crossprod(X, y))  ## one-column matrix to vector
XtX.Xty <- c(XtX %*% Xty)  ## one-column matrix to vector

for(i in 1:length(a)) {
  result2[,i] <- f(XtX.Xty, Xty, a[i])
  }

## compare with your `result`
all.equal(result, result2)
#[1] TRUE
```

And it turns out that we can get rid of the loop:

```
## "inline" function `f`
for(i in 1:length(a)) {
  result2[,i] <- XtX.Xty + a[i] * Xty
  }

## compare with your `result`
all.equal(result, result2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

```
## do it with recycling rule
for(i in 1:length(a)) {
  result2[,i] <- a[i] * Xty
  }
result2 <- XtX.Xty + result2

## compare with your `result`
all.equal(result, result2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

```
## now use `tcrossprod`
result2 <- XtX.Xty + tcrossprod(Xty, a)

## compare with your `result`
all.equal(result, result2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

I completely agree with you that your example code in the question is just a `"foo"`. And you may not have thought carefully about it when posting it. However, it suffices to show that when writing a loop, either an R loop or a C / C++ / FORTRAN loop, we should always seek to pull those loop-invariant out of the loop to reduce computational complexity.

Your concern is to get speedup with Rcpp (or any compiled language). You want to vectorize a section of R code that is not readily vectorized. However, `"%*%"`, `crossprod` and `tcrossprod` are mapped to BLAS (FORTRAN code) and are not R-level computations. You readily have everything vectorized.

Don't always blame the interpretation overhead (*as R is an interpreted language*) of an R-loop for the poor performance. Such overhead is insignificant if each iteration is doing some "heavy" computations, like big matrix computations (using BLAS) or fitting statistical models (like `lm`). In fact, if you do want to write such a loop with a compiled language, use `lapply` function. This function implements loop at C level, and calls R function for each iteration. Alternatively, [Ralf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51475141/4891738) is an Rcpp equivalent. In my opinion, a loop nest written in R code is more likely to be inefficient.

Comment: `+1`. Thank you for your reply. But I still wonder if someone who does not know `c++`, make use of `Rcpp` for speeding up `R` loops.

Comment: @  李哲源 This code is a kind of `foo` code. I just wonder if I can make use of `Rcpp` for `loops` of the functions including matrices or vectors and some parameters. Those matrix products are arbitrary.

Comment: @ 李哲源 Can I improve the performance for a function that is not optimized like `crossprod`?