# Is it possible to speed up code by a factor ~1000 using base-R?

Tags: r, algorithm, performance

The reproducible example below can be used as test case. I am looking for a  base-R solution because

- I am not experienced with C++ (to integrate Rcpp) or Java (to integrate rJava)
- Thus it could be that the "speed-problem" is inherent to the algorithm
- I like the reporting tools and the rapid prototyping advantages of R.

**Backround** according to @Gregor's input:

The original problem is in the field of dial-a-ride problems. Thus we face the question "is it better to merge two tours?" billions of times. The example below has the same structure (How far a two places appart? Which would be the best next location to stop? What is the result if we merge two tours?).
We know about the great [answer on how to speed up R-code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970284/5784831) but in our case we have an additional "business logic" which shows up in various `if-else` statements. Thus, it seems not possible to us, to achieve vectorized code when `if-else` statements are present - but may be we miss something.

**Reproducible Example**

```
generate_random_sequence <- function(nrows=1000) {
  x <- c(0, runif(nrows, min = 0, max = 100), 0)
  y <- c(0, runif(nrows, min = 0, max = 100), 0)
  loc <- c("Start", floor(runif(nrows, 1000, 9999)), "Start")
  return(data.table::data.table(x = x, y = y, loc = loc, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

dist <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return(sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2))
}

get_best_loc <- function(cur_loc, stop1, stop2) {
  d1 <- dist(cur_loc$x, cur_loc$y, stop1$x, stop1$y)
  d2 <- dist(cur_loc$x, cur_loc$y, stop2$x, stop2$y)
  if (d1 <= d2) {
    best_stop <- stop1
    stop_id <- 1L
  } else {
    best_stop <- stop2
    stop_id <- 2L
  }
  return(list(best_stop = best_stop, stop_id = stop_id))
}

combine_sequence <- function(t1, t2) {
  t_combined <- c(1, rep(NA, nrow(t1) + nrow(t2) - 4), 1)
  ind_max <- c(nrow(t1) - 1, nrow(t2) - 1)
  last_stop <- t1[1, ]
  ind_next_stop <- c(2, 2)
  ind_t_combined <- 1
  while (all(ind_next_stop <= ind_max)) {
    r <- get_best_loc(last_stop, 
                        t1[ind_next_stop[1],], t2[ind_next_stop[2],])
    best_stop <- r$best_stop; stop_id <- r$stop_id; rm(r)
    if (stop_id == 1) {
      ind_next_stop[1] <- ind_next_stop[1] + 1
    } else {
      ind_next_stop[2] <- ind_next_stop[2] + 1
    }
    ind_t_combined <- ind_t_combined + 1
    t_combined[ind_t_combined] <- stop_id
    last_stop <- best_stop
  }

  if (ind_next_stop[1] < ind_max[1]) {
    t_combined[(ind_t_combined + 1):(length(t_combined) - 1)] <- 
      t1$loc[ind_next_stop[1]:(nrow(t1) - 1)]
  } else {
    t_combined[(ind_t_combined + 1):(length(t_combined) - 1)] <- 
      t2$loc[ind_next_stop[2]:(nrow(t2) - 1)]
  }
  return(t_combined)
}

n <- 1e2
t1 <- generate_random_sequence(n)
t2 <- generate_random_sequence(n)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(combine_sequence(t1, t2),
                               times = 10L, unit = "s")
```

**Input from comments:**

When I use **profiling** I get the following output. To me it is not clear, if I have levers where I can obtain a speedup of x1000. (I would just be in the dark)

[image]

Code for profiling:

```
  profvis::profvis({
    t_combined <- c(1, rep(NA, nrow(t1) + nrow(t2) - 4), 1)
    ind_max <- c(nrow(t1) - 1, nrow(t2) - 1)
    last_stop <- t1[1, ]
    ind_next_stop <- c(2, 2)
    ind_t_combined <- 1
    while (all(ind_next_stop <= ind_max)) {
      r <- get_best_loc(last_stop, 
                        t1[ind_next_stop[1],], t2[ind_next_stop[2],])
      best_stop <- r$best_stop; stop_id <- r$stop_id; rm(r)
      if (stop_id == 1) {
        ind_next_stop[1] <- ind_next_stop[1] + 1
      } else {
        ind_next_stop[2] <- ind_next_stop[2] + 1
      }
      ind_t_combined <- ind_t_combined + 1
      t_combined[ind_t_combined] <- stop_id
      last_stop <- best_stop
    }

    if (ind_next_stop[1] < ind_max[1]) {
      t_combined[(ind_t_combined + 1):(length(t_combined) - 1)] <- 
        t1$loc[ind_next_stop[1]:(nrow(t1) - 1)]
    } else {
      t_combined[(ind_t_combined + 1):(length(t_combined) - 1)] <- 
        t2$loc[ind_next_stop[2]:(nrow(t2) - 1)]
    }
})
```

Comment: [See here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html) for resources on profiling R code.

Comment: Also, once you've identified performance bottlenecks, consider using Rcpp or rJava to speed up those parts without needing to port your entire codebase.

Comment: One potential problem is `rbind`, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990237/for-loop-in-r-looking-for-an-alternative/50991437#50991437.

Comment: It's looking better. I'll re-open, but please also describe your code in words. There are no comments, so it would be nice to have a description of the goal. You profiling shows that lots of time is spent in `get_best_loc`. But looking at the code it's not at all clear to me that what the goal of `combine_sequence`  is or why you need a `while` loop running one-at-a-time instead of, say, batching every 1000 together for some vectorization.